# NSManagedObject get parent object

Tags: xcode, core-data

I have an NSManagedObject who has a one to many relationship with the parent Object. How can I get the parent object using the child object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a `@property` to access it and then call the `@property`

```
id parent = [myChild parent];
```

Or you can access it via KVC

```
id parent = [myChild valueForKey:@"parent"];
```

Comment: Let me clarify my question, What I want is for instance I have a parent object (Dealers) and a dealer has many (cars), now in a tableview I'm showing all the cars there are, but as I show each car in the tableview I want to display the Dealers Name...So would that work?

Comment: I must be thick but I don't understand fully.  Say you've got two entities, 'dealers' and 'cars' with their own attributes.  You've done your fetchRequest on the 'cars' entity but want to get the 'dealers' name attribute and pop it in the tableViewCell.  A fuller code example would be swell.

Comment: There really isn't anything "fuller". The dealer is an object on the other side of a relationship. From an object perspective the Car instance has a pointer to the Dealer instance and you can access it via the accessors discussed in the original answer.